# Adding label text to coolbar in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a Eclipse RCP application and I want to add label text below each Action item on the coolbar as shown below in screenshot. I am using the sample code from the mail application and calling the setText method on action Item as follows:

```java
protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar) {
        IToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.RIGHT);
        coolBar.add(new ToolBarContributionItem(toolbar, "main"));   
        toolbar.add(openViewAction);

        openViewAction.setText("Open");// This is not setting any label text on the toolbar

        toolbar.add(messagePopupAction);


    }
```

Below is the screenshot of what I want to achieve:

[image]

What is the right way to do it. I tried looking at https://sourceforge.net/projects/rssowl but was not able to locate where it is getting set.

Edit : After forcing the text to display it shows the text **next** to icon. Is there a way to show it **below** the icon

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to force the text to show using `ActionContributionItem.MODE_FORCE_TEXT`:

```java
openViewAction.setText("Open");

ActionContributionItem openViewItem = new ActionContributionItem(openViewAction);

openViewItem.setMode(ActionContributionItem.MODE_FORCE_TEXT);

toolBar.add(openViewItem);
```

So you need to create the `ActionContributionItem` and add that to the tool bar rather than adding the action directly.

Comment: After forcing the text to display it shows the text **next** to icon. Is there a way to show it **below** the icon

Comment: Don't specify `SWT.RIGHT` on the `ToolBarManager` style.

Comment: Still same ..I cleared run time data as well..same result

Comment: `ActionContributionItem` seems to be doing things in an odd order and is confusing the image to right/below code in `ToolItem`. I can't see a way around it at present.

Comment: This seems to be working here : https://sourceforge.net/p/rssowl/code/HEAD/tree/branches/2.1.x/org.rssowl.ui/src/org/rssowl/ui/internal/ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.java

Comment: That code seems to be doing lots of extra work, for example in their 'CoolBarAdvisor' class.